# A question from Coleman's "aspects of symmetries''

Tags: quantum-field-theory, symmetry-breaking, instantons, ward-identity, axion

I know this question is a bit specialized and require rather deep background on Coleman's book [Aspects of Symmetries](https://books.google.de/books?id=PX2Al8LE9FkC&pg=PA308&lpg=PA309&dq=aspects%20of%20symmetry&source=bl&ots=6EQJeNaTOU&sig=QrR123YHDDqH60P55gErCTFDrRI&hl=zh-CN&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjRxtP65fXPAhVELcAKHTwDAREQ6AEIWjAI#v=onepage&q=aspects%20of%20symmetry&f=false). And I am sorry for that.
But I still would like to ask the question and hope some guys who occasionally have read that book can answer this question.

On page 309 (see the above link), Coleman talks about the chiral current (anomaly) $j_\mu^5$:
$$\partial^\mu j_\mu^5=\frac{N}{32\pi^3}\epsilon^{\mu\nu\lambda\sigma}(F_{\mu\nu}, F_{\lambda\sigma}),\tag{5.4}$$
where (,) is the Cartan inner product, but normally it is just the trace, i.e.
$$(T^a,T^b)=-2\rm{Tr}(T^aT^b).$$
The current $j^5_\mu$ is not conserved (the famous chiral anomaly), but we can define 
$$J^5_\mu=j^5_\mu-\frac{N}{16\pi^2}\epsilon_{\mu\nu\lambda\sigma}
(A^{\nu},F^{\lambda\sigma}-\frac{2}{3}A^{\lambda}A^{\sigma}).\tag{5.5}$$
And this new current $J^5_{\mu}$ is conserved. Then Coleman continues:

> If we work in a covariant gauge (and why should we not?), the added term commutes with the quark fields at equal times. Thus we can derive for Green's functions made of one $J_\mu^5$ and a string of gauge-invariant quark multilinears, chiral $U(1)$ Ward identities is of the usual form. And since these are of the usual form, they lead to the usual conclusion: chiral $U(1)$ is a symmetry: either Green's functions made of quark multiliears alone are $U(1)$ symmetric, or there are Goldstone poles in Green's functions for one $J_\mu^5$ and a string of quark multilinears

I can not understand this paragraph clearly. Specifically,

> If we work in a covariant gauge (and why should we not?), the added term commutes with the quark fields at equal times. Thus we can derive for Green's functions made of one $J_\mu^5$ and a string of gauge-invariant quark multilinears, chiral $U(1)$ Ward identities is of the usual form.

How to see that in the covariant gauge, the added term commutes with the quark fields at equal times? What would it be if the added term do not commute with the quark fields at equal times? Namely, why do we require the commutativity to obtain the usual form of Ward identities?

Comment: Reading Coleman before mastering the [Goldstone theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldstone_boson#Goldstone.27s_argument) might not be optimal. That section summarizes a devilishly subtle argument about the *evasion* of the Goldstone argument for the flavor singlet chiral current, so that the η' is not a normal (light) goldstone.

Comment: It might help to actually *add* the equation into the post so that people don't have to open Coleman to find out what eq. 5.5 and the "added term" you're talking about is.

Comment: @CosmasZachos Can you please recommend some materials to me so that I can understand the argument given by Coleman here?

Comment: @ACuriousMind Ok, I will do that soon.

Comment: Materials on the Goldstone Theorem? Kibble's http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Englert-Brout-Higgs-Guralnik-Hagen-Kibble_mechanism#Proof_of_the_theorem. The theorem and the SSB mechanism it underlies is one of *the* handful of pillars of QFT....

Comment: Coleman is reassuring the reader the commutativity of the extra term preserves the U(1) Ward identity; in the case of pseudoscalars the SSB mode of Goldstone's: the η' would comport with the pions. If there were  corrections, one would have to recheck that the new WI had the usual symmetry effects.

Comment: @CosmasZachos, Dear Cosmas, I think now I understand the Goldstone theorem and the ``Goldstone pole'' in Coleman's words. But I still can not see why the added term commutes with the quark fields at equal times in the covariant gauge.

Comment: Gauge fields commute with quark fields... are you objecting to (5.31)?

Comment: @CosmasZachos, Well I mean how to see the added term in Eq.(5.5) commutes with quark fields in the covariant gauge. I am not very clear here about your logic. I know Eq.(5.31) is the Ward identity. But at the moment I am just trying to understand Coleman's words cited above.

Comment: Don't different fields commute at all times?

Comment: @CosmasZachos Yes, but why does Coleman stress ``in the covariant gauge"...

Comment: Don't have the text here... go through the WIs and check what would go wrong otherwise... it is further down the book, if i recall...